# Cannot seem to fetch documents with subcollections

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

I have a tree-like structure with subcollections that I can build, insert objects into and fetch from, but I cannot list the documents in the middle.  The tree looks like

```
/TimeEntries/2018/2018-10/2018-10-15/Events
/TimeEntries/2018/2018-10/2018-10-22/Events
```

In the above, `2018` is a document, `2018-10` is a subcollection, and `2018-10-15` and `2018-10-22` are documents with `Events` subcollections.

This is made with something like

```
func SaveEvents(week time.Time, events []Event) {
    colref := client.Collection("TimeEntries").Doc(week.Format("2006")).Collection(week.Format("2006-01")).Doc(week.Format("2006-01-02")).Collection("Events")
    batch := client.Batch()

    for _, event := range events {
        batch.Set(colref.Doc(strconv.Itoa(event.Id)), event)
    }
    if _, err := batch.Commit(context.Background()); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to create event docs: %v", err)
    }
}
```

There are times when I'll want events by week and events by month.  I can fetch events by week right now, but to fetch events by month I have to fetch the list of documents in the middle of the tree, and then get their subcollections' documents.  Unfortunately, trying to list the documents in the middle of the tree doesn't work; this always logs `0 events`:

```
func FetchEventsForMonth(week time.Time) {
    colref := client.Collection("TimeEntries").Doc(week.Format("2006")).Collection(week.Format("2006-01"))

    snaps, err := colref.Documents(context.Background()).GetAll()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("cannot fetch docs: %v", err)
        return
    }

    log.Printf("%d events", len(snaps))
}
```

I can't see anything in the documentation that explains this behavior.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the following collection reference:

```
colref := client.Collection("TimeEntries").Doc(week.Format("2006")).Collection(week.Format("2006-01"))
```

It means that you are getting from the database **only** the documents within `2006-01` collection and only those documents, nothing more. Unfortunately, there is no way in Firestore to also get all the documents within `Events` collection, which is a subcollection within `2006-01-02` document in a single query. Queries in Firestore are shallow: they only get items from the collection that the query is run against. There is no way to get documents from another top-level collection and other collections or subcollections in a single query. Firestore doesn't support queries across different collections in one step. A single query may only use properties of documents in a single collection.

If you want to query your Cloud Firestore database for documents within a single collection by `documentId`, you can achieve this using  `FieldPath.documentId()` like this:

```
client.collection.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '<', 'yourDate').get();
```

But be aware that the document ids are **String** and therefore this will include documents with id like `2018-10-15` or `2018-10-22`. So when you order strings, the result are ordered lexicographically and I think that this is not what you want. So if you want to query a collection by numeric values, you'll need to write the document ID as a numeric value.

But the most efficient solution in this case would be to simplify your database by creating a single collection that holds `event` documents and add under each event object a date property so you can query your database according to it. In this case you can use all the functions that Firestore SDK provides and filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=).

Comment: _It means that you are getting from the database only the documents within 2006-01 collection and only those documents, nothing more._

That is exactly what I want -- the list of documents named (in this example) `2018-10-15` and `2018-10-22`.  I don't want the documents inside the `Events` subcollections under them.

Comment: For that, please see the official documentation regarding [func (Query) Select](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore) -> `Select returns a new Query that specifies the paths to return from the result documents. Each path argument can be a single field or a dot-separated sequence of fields, and must not contain any of the runes "˜*/[]".

An empty Select call will produce a query that returns only document IDs.`.

Comment: I've tried `iter := colref.Select().Documents(ctx)` (or with `.SelectPaths()`) and looping over `iter` doesn't return any documents.  I've also tried `iter := colref.Documents(ctx)`.

Comment: It doesn't return any docs or errors.  I have a `log.Printf` inside the loop that iterates over `iter` and it's never called.  (Nor are any of the error checks inside the loop triggered, either.)

I can put all my event entries under one collection, and add fields to each event like "YearMonth" or "WeekStart" with strings for the dates I'll later need, but then it becomes impossible to browse that collection using the web console.

Comment: But any other values from the database are displayed correctly, right?

Comment: Yes, if I try to fetch a document at the end of the tree, it works.  So, I can get `/TimeEntries/2018/2018-10/2018-10-22/Events/401675` and deserialize it to a struct (or read it as a `map[string]interface{}`), but not `/TimeEntries/2018/2018-10` or `/TimeEntries/2018`.  The error says it can't find it: `rpc error: code = NotFound desc = "projects/my-gcloud-project/databases/(default)/documents/TimeEntries/2018" not found`

Comment: Are you sure all of your variables that you pass to those functions are correct? And the result is an existing reference?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive there's no mistake there.